# Why is the colour of my model the same as its normal map?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

I am making condensation map for glass mug of donut tutorial series of "blender guru".
I have done correctly but it's still purple.what should I do?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have the Viewer node connected.

Remove it by CTRL+SHIFT+Left-clicking on the Principled shader. *(Assuming you have the 'Node Wrangler' addon enabled).*

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer.